# On indecomposable Polynomials. 

Tags: polynomials

Help needed!

**Def.**
Let $F(x _ 1,\dots,x _ n),G(x _ 1,\dots,x _ n)$ be two polynomials in $K[x _ 1,\dots,x _ n].$ $F,G$ are indecomposable iff there are no $u(x)\in K[x]$ with $\operatorname{deg}(u)\ge 2$ satisfying $F=u(H)$ for any $H\in K[x _ 1,\dots,x _ n]$.

**Prop.** If $F,G$ are two indecomposable polynomial and exist one variable polynomials $U _ 1(x),U _ 2(x)$ s.t. $U  _ 1(F)=U _ 2(G)$, then $G=aF+b$ for $a,b\in K$.

Is there an elementary proof to this proposition?  Note that $F,G$ has at least two variables or this proposition is trivially satisfied. 
Thanks alot!

Comment: Is there a non-elementary proof you are aware of?


Comment: Also, I assume that by "trivially satisfied" you mean "false", since you can have $U_1 = G\quad U_2 = F.$


Comment:  Igor Rivin: The only proof I know of is by showing that $K(F,G)$  has a single generator $w$, and then by arguing that $w$ could be taken to be a polynomial. (Which is basically the proof given below in the answer). However, I was told that a "simple and direct proof of just a few lines" existed.  So I was curious to what other approaches could be made?

Comment: Ancheng: since you were aware of the proof in that reference (Lemma 5.2 of http://math.univ-lille1.fr/~pde/bodin-debes-najib.pdf) I now withdraw the answer.